# Django URL namespace concept

Tags: django, url, namespaces

Simple question first: Is there any drawback in dynamically determining the URL namespace of an Django app within the view layer and passing the result as part of the context to templates? Why does Django does not do that as default behavior?

The thoughts behind: I understand that namespaces are a good idea to help Django in finding the right URLs from within my views even if they don't have unique names throughout a bigger project. They can also help in cases, where i may want to address views in other apps where i don't know or want to hardcode the URLs.

But I'm still pondering with the way the URL namespace concept is implemented in Django. As far as i understand, the applications in Django are meant to be "portable" so that they can be put into a python package and reused in another Django project without to much a headache. So i would expect that my app should be able to run within any namespace (or even none at all) that another Django project may be assigning it to.

But if i hardcode my namespace into the templates and views of my app (as apparently seems to be enforced by the official Django documentation) this is something that the other Django project must respect. My app can't be used without that namespace anymore. If there happens to be another app with the same namespace in that project some of the urls that map to non-unique view-names may be wrong.

I'm actually considering to address my problem by dynamically determining the given namespace and passing this into the context that is used for rendering my templates. So in my view functions (in views.py) i would have lines like this:

```
namespace = request.resolver_match.namespace+':' if request.resolver_match.namespace!='' else ''
context = { 'objects': object_list , 'namespace': namespace}
return render(request, 'MyApp/object.html', context)
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(namespace + 'detail', args=(object.id,)))
```

In my template files I can now write:

```
<a href="{% url namespace|add:'detail' object.id %}">{{ object.name }}</a>
```

This way i seem to be able to use my app with or without a namespace and even have it multiple times in the projects urls.py under different namespaces (Why would I ever do that - beside of obscuring a parameter in my url-design?). Of course if a need to know the namespace to the view of a foreign app where I want to link to there may be no way to avoid namespace-hardcoding except of maybe putting a second namespace into the context.